# Is there polyfill for css transform property in IE8

Tags: css, less, transform, css-transforms

I have the following mixin for cross-browser transform:

```
.transform (...) {
    -webkit-transform: @arguments; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
       -moz-transform: @arguments; /* Firefox 3.5+ */
        -ms-transform: @arguments; /* IE 9 */
         -o-transform: @arguments; /* Opera 10.5+ */
            transform: @arguments; /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

.translate(@x:0, @y:0) {
    .transform(translate(@x, @y));
}
```

And apply it something like the following:

```
#main {
   .translate(280px, 0);
}
```

But it's not wotk in [IE8 and Opera mini](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). Is there some fallback, polyfill or any for supporting it in therese browsers?

Comment: check this http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

Comment: For IE6+ there's `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix` which can simulate many css3 transform effects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few you can use, the ones suggested from modenizer are:

[css sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) and [transformie](https://github.com/pbakaus/transformie).

I'd argue though, that adding pollyfills to older browser like ie8 damages the performance of an already past it browser and lowers the user experience. Also, if you are adding pollyfills to mobile browsers you are adding to the loading times which in a 3g connection might put users off.

Comment: You can detect if the browser is IE8 and load the polyfill only in that case. You argument for 3g mobile networks is moot.

Comment: following this answer, I've gone with css sandpaper and had a helluva time debugging 400 bad requests - turns out that the following line `req.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");` needs to be `req.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");` - then it works!